# View my archives in Google Voice

Tags: google-voice

When I archive a message or voicemail in Google Voice, how can I see it again? Are they all stored in a particular location or folder?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the `History` section in the navigation options on the left-hand side.  You can click `History` to view everything, or one of the sub-options such as `Voicemail`.

Comment: Not any more!! Can't find archived voicemails anywhere in 2015.

Answer (score 0):

In the new ([2017-01-23](https://blog.google/products/google-voice/ringing-2017-updates-our-google-voice-apps/)) Google Voice, the "Archive" link is in the overflow menu.

In the left menu, click the three vertical dots. "Archive" is the fourth option.

[image: left navigation menu]

---

[image: overflow menu]